# HDMI weird behavior

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv, playstation, computer-behavior

I have a Sharp smart TV, I need to connect my laptop to the tv, I previously had PlayStation 3 connected.

When I connect my laptop through HDMI nothing happens, then I tried connecting PS3 again to see if it could be HDMI's fault, but everything worked it showed the PlayStation interface on the screen.
What is the problem? How do I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried switching your laptop to duplicate screen mode by pressing windows key + p and choosing duplicate ?

Comment: Yes, also just tried it again, still nothing showing

Comment: ok then unplug the PS3 and the hdmi cable from the tv and then turn off the tv and then plug your hdmi into the laptop and change the port of the hdmi if possible and turn on the tv and select the new source if possible btw are you sure you are selecting the correct source on the tv?

Comment: Did it, still doesn't work

Comment: Lol now I tried reconnecting PS3 and that isn't working either

Comment: That sounds like a poor quality HDMI cable.

Comment: But then wouldn't it act the same in every device?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be due to faulty HDMI cable.

I have found another one, and everything works perfectly with it!